# Roll your own widget factory

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

So for practice with Javascript, I wrote this lightweight widget factory which is similar in functionality (okay, that's a bit of a stretch) to jQuery's UI Widget factory. I was hoping I could get some pointers as far as idiom usage and also if there are any glaring problems with the below code.

```
var _CreateWidget = function(namespace, implementation) {
    _Widget = {
        _create: function() {},
        _destroy: function() {},
        _set: function() {},
        _get: function() {},
        options: {},
        context: undefined,
        namespace: namespace,
        apply: function(element) {
            this.context = element;
            element[namespace] = this;
            this._create();
        }
    };

    for (var item in implementation) {
        if (implementation.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            _Widget[item] = implementation[item];
        }
    }

    return _Widget;
}

Widget = function(namespace, implementation) {
    return function(element) {
        var instance = _CreateWidget(namespace, implementation);
        instance.apply(element);
        return instance
    };
}
```

An example widget would be defined as follows:

```
//Example widget
Page = Widget("page", {
    _create: function() {
        //initialization code here
    },
    _destroy: function() {

    },
    _set: function() {

    },
    _get: function() {

    },
    request: function() {
        //custom function
    },
    options: {
        url: ''
    }
});
```

And the widget would be applied to an element like so:

```
myElement = document.getElementById("myUniqueId");
appliedPageReference = Page(myElement);

myElement.page.request(); //One way to call the custom request() function;
appliedPageReference.request(); //Another way to call the custom request() function;
```

Comment: You're missing the `var` keyword in several places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Although DOM elements can be used like normal JavaScript objects, I'd avoid attaching JavaScript other than handlers. The problem is when they form [circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1493453/575527). In browser garbage collectors, they won't collect garbage if something still references them. If you accidentally form circular references, this will lead to memory leaks (unfreed memory)

  [jQuery avoids this by creating objects in an internal cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004655/575527) and assigns an ID to the element. That way, you are assigning a primitive to the element, not an object. This is how jQuery collects and manages event handlers, data attributes, and others.

  So a general tip is: *What is from JavaScript, stays in JavaScript. (And not cross over to the DOM)*
- In jQuery's case, the functions are not actually attached to the element. That's the purpose of the "jQuery object". In a gist, a jQuery object is just an [array-like object](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects) (let's call it "pseudo-array" from this point on), that contains DOM elements. The prototype of the jQuery object is where the functions live. These functions operate on each value in the collection.

  Executing a function in a jQuery object is not like this:

  ```
  someElement.doSomething();
  ```

  But rather, something like this:

  ```
  collectionOfStuff.forEach(function(DOMElement,i,arr){
    //do something for each in the collection
  });
  ```
- `Widget` in your code is some function that manufactures "widget templates" which are used to bind to your elements. Rather than having `Widget` return the template, why not make `Widget` your namespace. You can then create a function that attaches to the namespace.

  It would be synonymous to doing `jQuery.fn.extend(function(){...})`

  ```
  //define widget
  Widget.defineWidget('Page',function(){

    //local stuff, aka "private"
    var privateVar = 'foo';
    function privateFn(){...}

    //anything attached to `this` is "public"
    //we will execute this function, providing an object as `this`
    this.publicVar = 'bar';
    this.publicFn = function(){...}

  });

  //access widget
  var reference = Widget.Page(bindingTarget);
  ```

  `defineWidget` define a creator function into the namespace that uses the widget definition to build instances, something like:

  ```
  Widget.defineWidget = function(name,fn){

    //store
    wigetCache[name] = fn;

    //attach to namespace
    Widget[name] = function(){

      //BaseClass could be some constructor with prototype containing
      //all functions that widgets should have
      var instance = new BaseClass();

      //run the instance through the definition to attach the internals
      return fn.call(instance);
    } 
  }
  ```